# Android - How can i sync a method in mainActivity with a static boolean variable from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have a method in the `mainActivity`, this method Refresh my `RecyclerView`. I want sync that method to a `static boolean` variable and can be Called for every change of that `boolean` variable.

here's my Method:

```
public void RefreshView() {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerMainView);
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(context, getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

}
```

Comment: You can use [observer design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm). That's a general solution for these kinds of problems.

Comment: You should provide more context about what "another class" is and how it relates to your main activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Pass the context** of MainActivity to your class/fragment in the class constructor and use it call the MainActivity methods whenever your boolean variable is changed

```
if(booleanChanged){
((MainActivity) context).RefreshView();
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea. 1) You should not pass _anything_ in fragment / activity constructors. 2) This introduces a tight dependency between the component that has the boolean and the main activity. 3) You now have a memory leak for as long as you're holding on to that context reference.